# Qt + Google Protocol Buffers, Trouble linking libraries

Tags: qt, protocol-buffers, static-linking

Hopefully this is an easy question:

I am building an application with Qt and would like to use Google's Protocol Buffers.  I have downloaded and installed the protobuf source, now I want to link against it in my project.

My **.pro** file contains the line:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -libprotobuf
```

However, I get the error:

```
:: error: library not found for -llibprotobuf
```

when trying to compile.

I am assuming that I am doing something rather basic wrong.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the file is `libprotobuf.[so|a]`, the correct library link command is `-lprotobuf` (the lib prefix is implied)

Comment: Haha, knew it was simple!  Thanks!